# как из датафрейма размером 5*5 сделать датафрейм с одним столбцом

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Есть датафрейм размером 3х5

| 1 | 2 | 3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 095 | 093 | 094 |
| 109 | NaN | NaN |
| 09 | 10 | NaN |
| 019 | 020 | NaN |
| 04 | 05 | 123 |

Возможно ли из датафрейма 3Х5 сделать датафрейм 1Х11 без пустых значений

| 1 |
| --- |
| 095 |
| 109 |
| 09 |
| 019 |
| 04 |
| 093 |
| 10 |
| 020 |
| 05 |
| 094 |
| 123 |

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Примерно так:

```py
df1 = df.T.stack(dropna=True).to_frame().reset_index(drop=True)
```

Подсмотрено на [английском СО](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45863677/flatten-out-a-pandas-dataframe).

По шагам:

- `T` нужно, чтобы данные шли в нужном порядке
- `stack(dropna=True)` делает из матричного датафрейма линейную серию, попутно выкидывая `NA`
- `to_frame()` превращает серию обратно в датафрейм с одной колонкой (вроде бы на выходе нужен именно датафрейм)
- `.reset_index(drop=True)` выкидывает сложный мультииндекс, образовавшийся на первом шаге

То есть в принципе достаточно уже первых двух шагов, остальное делается чтобы привести результат в нужный/красивый вид.

Answer (score 5):

можно воспользоваться методом `melt`:

```
res = df.melt()["value"].dropna()
```

res:

```
0      95.0
1     109.0
2       9.0
3      19.0
4       4.0
5      93.0
7      10.0
8      20.0
9       5.0
10     94.0
14    123.0
```

Comment: Да, кстати, `melt` данные в правильном порядке схлопывает, зря я его поленился проверить )  Считаю этот ответ более коротким и правильным )